# jQuery is not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

jQuery is not working in IE7 while it works properly in IE8 & above, chrome and Fire Fox. I spend time but didn't get any clue so I am here, need help.

JQuery is:

```
$("#<%= Txt_Destination.ClientID %>").val(window.sessionStorage.getItem("Destination"));
```

I used Session to take the value in text box from the previous form.

```
document.getElementById('<%=Txt_Destination.ClientID%>').readOnly = true; //made it Read Only.

 var arr = new Array();
     arr = Route.split(',');
     $("#DDL_Route").html("");
     $("#DDL_Route").append($("<option></option>").val(0).html("Select"));
     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         var item = arr[i];
         $("#DDL_Route").append($("<option></option>").val(i + 1).html(item));
     }
```

It is used to have value in drop down from Route variable which has multiple values comma separated

```
 $('#DDL_Route').change(function () {
         var selectedvalue = $('#DDL_Route option:selected').attr('text');
         if (selectedvalue == 'Select') {
             alert('Please select value from dropdown');
             $('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val(" ");
             return false;
         } Validation.

$("#<%= Btn_Save.ClientID %>").click(function () {
         var numericReg = /^[1-9][0-9]{9}$/;  // check only digit
         if (!numericReg.test($('#<%= Txt_Number.ClientID %>').val())) {  
         // if not digit, return false
             alert("Please enter proepr contact no in Text Box");
             return false;
         }
         else if ($('#<%= Txt_Number.ClientID %>').val() == "") { // if it is blank, return false
             alert("Please enter 10 digit contact no in Text Box");
             return false;
         }
         //if value is Select from drop down, return false else if ($('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val() == " " || $('#DDL_Route option:selected').attr('text') == "Select") { 
             alert("Please select value from dropdown");
             return false;
         }
         else { // all conditions satisfied, return true
             return true;
         }
     }); Submit action with validation.
```

Can you anyone tell me what is the wrong here which is IE7 not
 supporting

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.sessionStorage` is not supported in IE7

Comment: +1 Take a look at [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) for gracefully degrading storage options

Comment: Thanks Tushar. Its working now by method window.sessionStorage